# show that the nullspace of $P$ is invariant when applying state matrix

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Assume $P$ solves the Riccati equation

$${A^T}P + PA - PB{B^T}P + {C^T}C = 0$$

show that nullspace($P$) is invariant up to the application of the state matrix and show that $kernel(P) \subset C$

Attempt: I have no idea how to prove first part, but for second part: To show that kernel$(P)  \subset $kernel$(C)$ multiply the algebraic Riccati equation by $x\in$kernel$(P)$
\begin{eqnarray}
{A^T}Px + PAx - PB{B^T}Px + {C^T}Cx = 0
\end{eqnarray}
and use the fact that $Px=0$ and $PAx=0$ which gives
\begin{eqnarray}
{C^T}Cx = 0
\end{eqnarray}
and hence $x\in$kernel$(C)$

Comment: Where did you find this question? It seems like something is missing. Also, is the definition of invariance this one? If $S=\mathrm{span}(A)$, then $P$ is $A$-invariant if $PS\subset S$?

Comment: @KBS yes, that's the definition. No, that was the question, nothing is missing. My intuition says I gotta perform some algebraic manipulations to prove it!!

Comment: Yeah, but the title does not seem to match the contents. In the title, you say that the kernel of $P$ is $A$-invariant whereas in the question you say that $P$ is $A$-invariant.

Comment: @KBS that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: So, in this case, that means that $A\mathrm{ker}(P)\subset \mathrm{ker}(P)$.

Comment: @KBS yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the Riccati equation is satisfied. Then, we have that

$$x^T\left({A^T}P + PA - PB{B^T}P + {C^T}C\right)x = 0$$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Now if we assume that $x\in\mathrm{ker}(P)$, then we get

$$x^TC^TCx = 0$$ for all $x\in\mathrm{ker}(P)$. Since $x^TC^TCx=||Cx||^2$, then  $x^TC^TCx=0$ if and only if $Cx=0$. This implies that $x\in\mathrm{ker}(C)$ and therefore that $\mathrm{ker}(P)\subset\mathrm{ker}(C)$. This proves the inclusion.

For the invariance, we want to show that the satisfiability of the Riccati equation implies that for all $x\in\mathrm{ker}(P)$ we have that $PAx=0$, i.e. $Ax\in\mathrm{ker}(P)$. So, we have that

$$\left({A^T}P + PA - PB{B^T}P + {C^T}C\right)x=0$$
for all $x\in\mathrm{ker}(P)$. This yields

$$\left(PA + {C^T}C\right)x=0.$$

But we know that $\mathrm{ker}(P)\subset\mathrm{ker}(C)$, so we get that

$$PAx=0,$$

which shows implies that $\mathrm{ker}(P)\subset A\mathrm{ker}(P)$. This proves the result.